# OsTicket Repopulate user__cdata when creating a field form user (Null or zero)

Tags: php, mysql, osticket

I have a problem when creating a field for the user form. I know that when creating a field, the user__cdata table is recreated and repopulated. However, when repopulating the user__cdata table the field values are NULL or 0.

I made a PHP script to repopulate this data based on the form_entry_values table, which worked.

But, when creating a new field, again the user__cdata table is repopulated with values of NULL or zero.

1. Table user__cdata with data:

   [image: table with data]
2. When I create a field in the user form, the data looks like this:

   [image: data after filed created]

   Version:

   [image: versions]

Upgrading is not an option for me at the moment as there are some features that have been customized.

I hope the user__cdata table doesn't lose its data when creating a new field in the user form.

Comment: The script you're talking about is missing in your question. Also, as much as possible, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). And for testing/development purposes, have a system near you, you can make snapshots of and the not hope but just test, if it's loosing data or not. Such question you always need to be able answer by yourself, we know nothing about your system. And as usual, consider a [mre].